# How to get access values of object programmatically

Tags: typescript

Assume function `foo` with 2 parameters:

1. `obj` is an object
2. `arr` is an array of strings

members of `arr` are the names of properties in `obj`, e.g.
`obj[arr[0]][arr[1]]` has a value if `arr` has at least 2 members.
How to get the value of the property in `obj` which `arr` points on?

**Note:** `obj` is typed and old school iteration throws error.

**Example:**
`obj` could be

```
{
  pro1: 'a',
  prop2: {
    prop21: 'b',
    prop22: ['c', 'd']
  }
}
```

and `arr` could be

```
['prop2', 'prop21']
```

I don't have any information about `obj` and `arr`, I just know

```
obj['prop2']['prop21']
```

certainly has a value and this phrase doesn't throw this error:

> can not read property prop21 of undefined

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you're asking for?

Comment: cast it to any then: arr.reduce((a, b) => a[b], obj as any)

Comment: @NitzanTomer I edited mu question and added an example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right then:

```
let obj = {
    pro1: "a",
    prop2: {
        prop21: "b",
        prop22: ["c", "d"]
    }
};

function getValue(obj: any, keys: string[]): any {
    let index = 0,
        current: any = obj;

    while (current[keys[index]]) {
        current = current[keys[index++]];
    }

    return current;
}

console.log(getValue(obj, ["prop2", "prop21"])); // b
console.log(getValue(obj, ["prop2", "prop22"])); // ["c", "d"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09pro1%3A%20%22a%22%2C%0D%0A%09prop2%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09prop21%3A%20%22b%22%2C%0D%0A%09%09prop22%3A%20%5B%22c%22%2C%20%22d%22%5D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getValue(obj%3A%20any%2C%20keys%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%09let%20index%20%3D%200%2C%0D%0A%09%09current%3A%20any%20%3D%20obj%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09while%20(current%5Bkeys%5Bindex%5D%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09current%20%3D%20current%5Bkeys%5Bindex%2B%2B%5D%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09return%20current%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(getValue(obj%2C%20%5B%22prop2%22%2C%20%22prop21%22%5D))%3B%20%2F%2F%20b%0D%0Aconsole.log(getValue(obj%2C%20%5B%22prop2%22%2C%20%22prop22%22%5D))%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22c%22%2C%20%22d%22%5D))